# Is there .Rowsource for column?

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a code for a combobox **cbClient** which chooses user picks a name of a client then a dependable combobox **cbOPsite** chooses a plant site related to the corresponding client that was picked.

The problem I am having is regarding the second combobox not listing out all the Plant sites instead it only shows "Albian" which is only one of the other plant Sites as shown below: 
[image]

Here is the table for Client and Site names:
[image]

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Private Sub cbClient_Change()
Select Case cbClient.value
    Case Is = "Athabasca Oil"
        cbOPSite.RowSource = "Athabasca_Oil"

    Case Is = "BlackPearl Resources "
        cbOPSite.RowSource = "BlackPearl_Resources"

    Case Is = "Brunei Methanol Company"
        cbOPSite.RowSource = "Brunei_Methanol"

    Case Is = "Centrica"
        cbOPSite.RowSource = "Centrica"

    Case Is = "CNRL"
        cbOPSite.RowSource = "CNRL"
    End Select
End Sub
```

So I am thinking its the .RowSource that is causing the issue and so how could the .Rowsource be changed to a column? Since I have tried .ColumnSource and doesn't work.

Comment: Can you be more specific when you say: "So how would you change the .Rowsource to column?" Are those named ranges you have defined in your workbook ("CNRL", "Centrica", etc?) If so, scoped to workbook or worksheet level?

Comment: Format your data in rows... not sure I understand the question or the issue.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Yes, they are named ranges. The (vertical green column) is a named range for operating client (e.g.CNRL) and for each individual client there are Plant sites which are named ranges horizontally from each of those clients (e.g. Albian Plant).

Comment: @MathieuGuindon My question is how would you use a similar function like .RowSource for columns.

Comment: `RowSource` isn't a function, it's a property of the dropdown control that expects data shaped a certain way. You make your data fit that format, not the other way around.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon There should be some kind of alternative, is there not?

Comment: @GoldFusion - there is no alternative using `.RowSource`. It's very easy to transpose your data. The only alternative is to load the items in `cbOPsite` via code on the change of `cbClient`, by looping through your columnar list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can look into `.List` property instead as an alternative?

Here is a small example:

- Data turned into named ranges:

[image]

[image]

- Quick userform with two comboboxes and following code:

[image]

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Me.ComboBox2.Clear
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    If .Range(ComboBox1.Value).Count = 1 Then
        Me.ComboBox2.AddItem .Range(ComboBox1.Value)
    Else
        Me.ComboBox2.List = Application.Transpose(.Range(ComboBox1.Value))
    End If
End With

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Me.ComboBox1.List = Array("Athabasca_Oil", "BlackPearl_Resources", "Brunei_Methanol", "Centrica", "CNRL")

End Sub
```

- Changing combobox1 will change the `.List` property of the second one (unless the named range only hold one cell, because otherwise that would error out):

[image]